# Django: simplifying a view

Tags: python, django

I have the following simple view. Is there any way I can make it more dynamic?

```
# ...

if 'folding' not in request.session:
    request.session['folding'] = {'shop':False,'users':False,'chat':False}

# ...

def update_folding_view(request,category,is_folded):
    if request.is_ajax():
        folding = request.session['folding']
        if 'shop' in category:
            folding.shop = is_folded
        if 'users' in category:
            folding.users = is_folded
        if 'chat' in category:
            folding.chat = is_folded
        request.session['folding'] = folding
    else:
        raise Http404
```

Comment: What do you mean by making it more dynamic

Comment: as folding is a dict:
for key in category: [newline]
    folding[key] = is_folded

Comment: Should have thought of that. My heads not working today

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I got:

```
from collections import defaultdict

...

if 'folding' not in request.session:
    request.session['folding'] = defaultdict(bool)

...

def update_folding_view(request, category, is_folded):
    if not request.is_ajax():
         raise Http404
    for item in category:             
        request.session['folding'][item] = is_folded
```